# relative path issue with mocking/patching in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock, relative-import

I am trying to mock a method called `get_value_from_cache` which is being used in `main.api.funds` file. My project directory is as follows.

```
my_rest_api
    - python
        - __init__.py
        - main
            - __init__.py
            - api
                - __init__.py
                - funds.py
        - tests
            - __init__.py
            - conftest.py
            - test_resource.py
```

I am writing my test cases in `test_resource.py` and using `pytest-mock`.
Here's my test case:

```
def test_fund_attributes_by_fund_port_id_with_cache(client: FlaskClient, mocker: MockerFixture):
    mocker.patch('main.api.funds.get_value_from_cache', return_value=[
        {
            'name': 'Fund Name'
        }
    ])

    heads = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {TEST_BEARER}'
    }

    res = client.get('/funds/0040', headers=heads)
    assert len(res.json) == 1
```

I am getting the error:

> **E           AttributeError: module 'main.api' has no attribute 'funds'**

The pipeline deploys the project in `python` folder. I am not sure, why it is not able to figure out the path? If I use relative path `..main.api.funds.get_value_from_cache`, I get the following error:

> E       ValueError: Empty module name

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: usually when it finds part of the import path, it means you have another package with the same name installed in your path. One way to confirm that would be to open a python console, import main.api and do dir(main.api). This will show you what you have inside the package. If you don't find funds, it would indicate you have another main.api in your path.

Comment: @Ssayan, it is showing funds. Not really showing why is it not able to find out funds in the patch method

Comment: OK. Would that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848315/pytest-mocker-fixture-mock-module-from-where-it-is-defined-and-not-where-it-is-u) help?

Comment: In your test code, do you `import main.api.funds`? Because importing only `main.api` wont automatically import `funds` unless you explicitly import it in the `__init__.py` file.